# Android NDK cmake compile assembly(*.s) files

Tags: android, assembly, android-ndk, cmake

I am using Android Studio 2.2.2 with cmake and Android NDK. I have a library that which contains several .s (assembler) files that I compile for my projects.

Until cmake, when I used Android.mk files I had this files compiled/linked without any problems while on cmake a get compiler errors like:

> lib\arm_android\armfrag.s:1:2: error: unexpected token at start of statement
>     @********************************************************************
>      ^
>     libs\arm_android\armfrag.s:2:2: error: unexpected token at start of statement
>     @*                                                                  *
>      ^

armfrag file containt at the top commented something like:

> @********************************************************************
>   @*                                                                  *
>   @* THIS FILE IS ...................................................................................

I think from this that my cmake can`t read this assembly files but the comments are not the only problem since I removed the comments and I still get errors.

My cmake looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)

set(can_use_assembler TRUE)
enable_language(ASM)

add_definitions(-DANDROID -DNDEBUG -DOC_ARM_ASM)

add_library(omnitus STATIC
    ../../../../libs/lib/arm_android/armbits.s 
    ../../../../libs/lib/arm_android/armfrag.s 
    ../../../../libs/lib/arm_android/armidct.s 
    ../../../../libs/lib/arm_android/armloop.s 
    ../../../../libs/lib/arm/armopts-gnu.s              
)

target_include_directories(omnitus PUBLIC
    ../../../../libs/include
)

target_include_directories(omnitus PUBLIC
    ../../../../libs/lib/arm
)

target_include_directories(omnitus PUBLIC
    ../../../../libs/include
)
```

Do anyone have any idea why is this failing with cmake and working with old Android.mk files ?

Cheers

*** Added ***

With verbose I get same errors but with this in addtion:

```
Android clang version 3.8.256229  (based on LLVM 3.8.256229)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
clang.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-D ANDROID'
clang.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-D ARM'
clang.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-D NDEBUG'
clang.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-D OC_ARM_ASM'  
clang.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-MD'
clang.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-MT      CMakeFiles/omnitus.dir/lib/arm/armopts-gnu.s.o'
clang.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-MF CMakeFiles\omnitus.dir\lib\arm\armopts-gnu.s.o.d'
```

*** Added modified cmake file ***

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)

set(can_use_assembler TRUE)
enable_language(ASM)

add_definitions(-v -DANDROID -DNDEBUG -DOC_ARM_ASM)

if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL armv7-a)
set(TEST_SOURCES ../../../../libs/lib/arm_android/armbits.s 
               ../../../../libs/arm_android/armfrag.s
               ../../../../libs/arm_android/armidct.s 
               ../../../../libs/arm_android/armloop.s
               ../../../../libs/lib/arm/armopts-gnu.s       
               )
endif()

add_library(omnitus STATIC ${TEST_SOURCES}              
)

target_include_directories(omnitus PUBLIC
    ../../../../libs/include
)

target_include_directories(omnitus PUBLIC
    ../../../../libs/arm
)

target_include_directories(omnitus PUBLIC
    ../../../../libs/include
)
```

Comment: Have you made sure that your library is being built only for ARM?

Comment: @Michael - Yes, I have specified in my gradle file abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a' and in Cmake with my definitions for ARM

Comment: Could you add `-v` to your flags and check if you get a line that says `Target: bla bla bla` when clang is invoked to assemble your assembly files? What target does it state?

Comment: @Michael - Samo errors, only this is adiotion. Please check updated answer. To long to write it here

Comment: Well, that doesn't look right (the target being `x86_64-unknown-linux`). Have you tried conditionally adding your assembly sources based on `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` as in [this example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/8f13499df723afd76c2db2264b82ba3b131cb4ad/tests/build/build-assembly-file/CMakeLists.txt)?

Comment: @Michael - I have modified my cmake with this (check updated question for cmake version) I get the same errors in my console.

Comment: I have added in my cmake file message("CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR  is ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}") and I get "CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR  is armv7-a"

Answer (score 0):

So far, for ARMv7 and ARMv8 architectures, you have to write assembly code in the C source file in inlined assembly style.

Android Studio just added YASM assembler for x86 and x86-64 architectures.